# The size of the template class

Tags: c++, class

I have a problem with something like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class X {
  T1 a;
  T2 b;
};

int main() {
 std::cout << sizeof(X<int,char>) << std::endl;
 std::cout << sizeof(X<int,int>) << std::endl;
 std::cout << sizeof(X<char,char>) << std::endl;
};
```

The output from gcc 4.4.7 is

```
8
8
2
```

I do not understand why the first result is 8. For me it should be 6. The same is with double/int template args (gives 16, not 12). I checked also, that this behaviour is independent of whether I use template class or normal class with only 2 members int and char.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Answer (score 1):

That is because of [structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). Generally the compiler will try to align objects (by padding) to a particular byte boundary, and both `4-byte` and `8-byte` boundaries are common.

[This page](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) discusses the same idea in `C`, but it is similar although not exactly the same in `C++`.